# How i can put 2 dicts in a list and use in dirscord webhook?

Tags: python, dictionary, discord

I need to put 2 dicts at same time from a list in discord webook?, i have problem with this i cant use dicts without parentheses because is in a list.

````
from discordwebhook import Discord
t = []

z = {"name": "2222", "value": '2222'}
y= {"name": "3333", "value": '3333'}

t.append(z)
t.append(y)


img = 'https://p4.wallpaperbetter.com/wallpaper/806/571/730/microsoft-windows-windows-10-galaxy-tent-wallpaper-preview.jpg'

discord = Discord(url="https://discord.com/api/webhooks/00000000")
discord.post(
      embeds=[
           {
              "title":  'NAME PERSON ',
              "fields": [
                {"name": "1111", "value": '1111'}, t,      # i need t equal 2 dicts at at once
               
               ],                               

               "thumbnail": {"url": img},  
               "footer": {
                   "text": "Example :)",
                   "icon_url": img, 
              },
           }
       ],
   )```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `*` symbol to extract all data inside list:

```
....
"fields": [
                {"name": "1111", "value": '1111'}, *t
               
               ]
...
```

ex:

```
ex = [
           {
              "title":  'NAME PERSON ',
              "fields": [
                {"name": "1111", "value": '1111'}, *t,      # i need t equal 2 dicts at at once
               
               ],                               

               "thumbnail": {"url": "img"},  
               "footer": {
                   "text": "Example :)",
                   "icon_url": "img", 
              },
           }
]
print(ex)
```

output:

```
[{'fields': [{'name': '1111', 'value': '1111'},
   {'name': '2222', 'value': '2222'},
   {'name': '3333', 'value': '3333'}],
  'footer': {'icon_url': 'img', 'text': 'Example :)'},
  'thumbnail': {'url': 'img'},
  'title': 'NAME PERSON '}]
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work, maybe the web hook format n allows it, I don't know what to do

Comment: @JONH can you share error message. And try `json.dumps(your_data)`

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it from *t, thanks so much you save me.